# Make undo during I-search revert last call to ding

Tags: isearch, keyboard-macros, undo

Entering a failing search string during I-search triggers a call to `ding()`. If this happens during a macro recording that ding when the macro is being played will abort the macro which in turns reverts all changes being made during the execution of that macro possibly with the exception of file system operations.

As making a mistake during I-search is (at least for me) a quite common mistake it would be very convenient to have an undo-call in I-search remove any calls to `ding()` from the macro recording triggered by the undoed key press.

Comment: It may just be me, but I cannot make any sense out of your description.  Your second sentence in particular is probably missing some words (and certainly missing some commas), which makes it hard to understand. Also, what's a `ding`?

Comment: Function `ding` rings the bell (e.g. when an error occurs). Is this about Isearch or keyboard macros? You had the tag for the latter but I changed it to the former.

Comment: How can undo "revert last call to ding"? Would that involve un-ringing the bell?

Comment: Of course not. This has nothing to do with sounds. The bell is a function that aborts the execution of the macro. I suggest you try the use case out. This is about being able to undo mistakes when entering the search string during I-search in macros without having to rerecord the whole macro from the start which can be very annoying when making such mistake somewhere at the end of a complex macro.

Comment: I suggest you describe your use case in more detail in the question: e.g. it was not clear that the question had anything to do with keyboard macros and as @Drew mentioned in a comment, he removed the tag (presumably because he did not see the relevance), and he asked you to verify. I added it back now, but it is not clear from the question that you are talking about keyboard macros. In particular, you should add your comment to the question: it's a much clearer description of the problem.

Comment: I updated the description.

Comment: `ding` does not abort the recording, but whatever does abort the recording might also call `ding`. Since the question has nothing to do with sounds, you shouldn’t use the bell tag or even mention the `ding` function. You should simply say that if you have a typo during an incremental search while recording a macro, the recording ends prematurely (it’s simpler and less confusing). However, I cannot reproduce this, so it may be something you have configured. Try running `emacs -Q` and trying it again; if the problem goes away then you will have narrowed the problem down significantly.

Comment: `ding` doesn't interrupt the recording of a macro, but it *does* abort execution of a macro -- so if the `ding` gets replayed, the remainder of the recording will not be replayed.  You can fix this fairly easily by editing the macro recording (refer to the manual).

Comment: Press `f4` to start macro, `C-s` to enter I-search, enter a string that doesn't exist in the buffer, press `Enter`, and finally `f4` to end the macro. Now pressing `f4` will ring the bell and abort the macro.

Comment: @Nordlöw Per my previous comment, you can edit the macro to fix the search string.

Comment: Yes, thanks. But far from as convenient as having undo during I-search automatically remove a potentially ding associated with previous input character.